# How to make arrows in Carousel Slider responsive?

Tags: flutter

I am making a Carousel Slider with the package carousel_slider and is working fine, and it is controlled by arrows and I want to make the arrows stays on each end of the carousel. When on full screen size I achived it with padding the thing is when I resize the screen the arrows do not stay on each end of the slider. How do I achieve it?

Here is my code so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:frontend_fst/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:frontend_fst/components/cards.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

class FSTCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FSTCarouselState createState() => _FSTCarouselState();
}

class _FSTCarouselState extends State<FSTCarousel> {
  late FSTCards cards = const FSTCards();
  CarouselController carouselController = CarouselController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: carouselSizedBox),
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 200),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Categoria',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    color: mainFSTColor,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: carouselSizedBox),
        Stack(
          children: [
            CarouselSlider(
            items: [
              cards,
            ],
            carouselController: carouselController,
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: 250.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              autoPlay: true,
              autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                  const Duration(milliseconds: autoAnimationDuration),
              viewportFraction: 0.8,
            ),
          ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 85, right: 85, top: 100),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => carouselController.previousPage(
                            duration: const Duration(
                                milliseconds: manualAnimationDuration),
                            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_before_rounded),
                        iconSize: 40,
                        splashRadius: 0.01,
                        color: mainFSTColor,
                      ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => carouselController.nextPage(
                            duration: const Duration(
                                milliseconds: manualAnimationDuration),
                            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next_rounded),
                        iconSize: 40,
                        splashRadius: 0.01,
                        color: mainFSTColor
                    ),
                  )
                ]
              ),
            )
         ]
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: I should add that this class is being called inside a ListView, here is the code from where it is called:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:frontend_fst/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:frontend_fst/components/cards.dart';
import 'package:frontend_fst/components/sideBar.dart';
import 'package:sidebarx/sidebarx.dart';
import 'package:frontend_fst/components/carousel.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'main_screen_web';

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  late FSTCards cards = const FSTCards();
  late FSTSideBar sideBar = FSTSideBar(
      controller: SidebarXController(selectedIndex: 0, extended: true));
  late FSTCarousel carousel = FSTCarousel();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(70),
          child: AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: secondaryFSTColor),
              title: Image.asset(companyLogo, height: 80, width: 85)),
        ),
        drawer: sideBar,
        body: ListView(
            children: [
          ...List.generate(13, (index) {
            return carousel;
          })
        ]));
  }
}
```

Here is how it looks on full screen size:

[image]

And here is how it looks when shrinked or resized:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think using Row() is better than using Stack().

how about fix your codes like under these codes using Row() instead of Stack():

```
Row(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 85, top: 100),
            child: Flexible(
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () => carouselController.previousPage(
                    duration: const Duration(
                        milliseconds: manualAnimationDuration),
                    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_before_rounded),
                iconSize: 40,
                splashRadius: 0.01,
                color: mainFSTColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          CarouselSlider(
            items: [
              cards,
            ],
            carouselController: carouselController,
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: 250.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              autoPlay: true,
              autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                  const Duration(milliseconds: autoAnimationDuration),
              viewportFraction: 0.8,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 85, top: 100),
              child: Flexible(
                child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => carouselController.nextPage(
                        duration: const Duration(
                            milliseconds: manualAnimationDuration),
                        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next_rounded),
                    iconSize: 40,
                    splashRadius: 0.01,
                    color: mainFSTColor),
              ))
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Hello there and thank you for your answer, I just returned from my vacations and tried your suggestion. But when I run it I get this error:

Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width.

Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of horizontal space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.

Comment: Also I added an Edit from where the my Carousel is being called.